# Не загружается файл на ftp curl

Tags: php-curl

Я хочу сделать загрузку файла с компьютера и сразу на FTP сервер.

С формы я отправляю POST запрос:

```
<!-- название папки на FTP севрере -->
fileDir: /HASP/  
<!-- название файла -->
fileName: apple-touch-icon-180x180.png
<!-- сам файл -->
file: (binary)
```

В PHP

```
$ftp_server = 'ftp://srv.org/';
$user = test;
$password = test321;
$fileDir = $_POST["fileDir"];
$file = $_FILES['file'];

 if($fileDir == '/'){
   $source = '';
 } else {
    $source = $fileDir;
 }
    $ch = curl_init();
    $fp = fopen($file['tmp_name'], 'r');

    curl_setopt_array($ch, [
        CURLOPT_URL => $ftp_server . $source . $file['name'],
        CURLOPT_USERPWD => $user.':'.$password,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 86400,
        CURLOPT_UPLOAD => 1,
        CURLOPT_INFILE => $fp,
        CURLOPT_INFILESIZE => filesize($file['tmp_name'])
    ]);
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {

        $msg = curl_error($ch);
    }
    else {

        $msg = 'File uploaded successfully.';
    }

    curl_close ($ch);

    $return = array('msg' => $msg);

    echo json_encode($return);
```

В $return приходит "File uploaded successfully", но самого файла я почему-то на FTP так и не увидел. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: вы только опции выставляете и проверяете код завершения именно установки опций. запрос надо выполнять через curl_exec

Answer (score 0):

Забыл добавить curl_exec($ch);